# Is there any benefit in allowing foreign lobbying in a country?

Tags: united-states, lobbying, foreign-interference

> Despite calling for a ban on foreign lobbying, in which Americans
> lobby lawmakers and the public for foreign interests, Republican 2024
> presidential hopeful Nikki Haley has raised tens of thousands of
> dollars in political donations from foreign lobbyists, disclosure
> reports show.
>
> The U.S. ambassador to the U.N. under the Trump administration, Haley
> has recently been campaigning on her opposition to foreign lobbying,
> saying that embassies -- and not private consultants or lobbyist
> agents -- should represent foreign interests in the U.S.
>
> Banning foreign lobbying has been part of her stump speech against aid
> to foreign countries, especially money she suggests is going to
> countries whose interests seem to be at odds with those of the United
> States.

https://abcnews.go.com/US/nikki-haley-slams-foreign-lobbyists-fundraising/story?id=99704708

Is there any benefit in allowing foreign lobbying in a country? Nikki Haley called for a ban on foreign lobbying. She has been campaigning on her opposition to foreign lobbying, saying that embassies should represent foreign interest in the U.S. I was wondering if there's any advantage for allowing foreign lobbying, because if there weren't any advantage in doing so, I think the U.S. would have outlawed it a long time ago.

Comment: Interesting question. If one takes the position that there's such intrinsic demand for it that it's going to happen at scale even if forbidden, then one could argue that it would make regulation of it possible, even if imperfect. I.e. regularize it, bring it into the light, and have standard rules, so at least nobody is deceived by what's happening.

Comment: @PeteW see the comment below re FARA - that's exactly that

Comment: IMHO the important question is 'benefit for whom ?'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think there is an advantage in allowing foreign lobbying, but there is a *dis*advantage in *dis*allowing foreign lobbying: it may be considered a violation of the freedom of speech. Any lobbyist could be shut down by claiming he/she is "representing foreign interests".

Comment: Lobbyists have to register, I assume they have to state who they're representing in this registration. Also, political contributions are considered speech, but election laws prohibit foreign contributions.

Answer (score 5):

> Is there any benefit in allowing foreign lobbying in a country?

Of course. Foreign countries need to find ways to influence politicians, and it works both ways. Also, foreign lobbying may not necessarily be foreign *governments'* lobbying. Can be a foreign opposition, too. In which case, embassy may not be willing/able/capable of properly representing these interests. It can be business interests, or religious groups. Or, it can be non-governmental entities or unrecognized entities (for example Taiwan doesn't actually have a formal embassy in the US).

> Nikki Haley called for a ban on foreign lobbying.

I don't think this is possible in the US, the US constitution explicitly allows free speech and petitioning the government without hindrance ([the First Amendment](https://constitution.congress.gov/constitution/amendment-1/)).

Comment: Can sure make it complicated though -- FARA. Also, historically https://firstamendment.mtsu.edu/article/bad-tendency-test/

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat FARA requires disclosure, not forbids the action. Lobbyist are [required to be registered even for domestic purposes](https://www.senate.gov/legislative/Lobbying/Lobby_Disclosure_Act/4_Registration_of_Lobbyists.htm). Besides, to the point of Nikki Haley's campaign, FARA is already the law of the land.

Comment: @Dolphin613Motorboat for the second link, see the last paragraph. the concept is quite outdated. Sure, appointing reactionary justices can help reverse certain trends in Constitutional law, but I was describing the *current* state of affairs

Comment: Indeed, the U.S. Constitution expressly recognizes that the U.S. will have foreign ambassadors and diplomats, and what are foreign ambassadors but foreign lobbyists? Pretty much, that is 80%-90% of the job of being an ambassador. It's important to distinguish lobbying itself from contributing money to political campaigns (which isn't even truly lobbying in and of itself). Lobbying is about voice and persuasion through sharing information, not authority to change policy itself. Knowing how foreign governments and businesses and NGOs will be impacted by U.S. laws has value in drafting U.S. laws.

Answer (score 1):

I will take as a given that there are advantages to a country of its government and its private entities (people and companies) dealing with entities outside that country. This could be importing things from another country, exporting things to another country, having planes owned by an airline based in that country flying to another country (and vice versa), tourism and other visits in both directions, tax treaties, pension treaties, free trade agreements and much more. (Yes, there may also be disadvantages, and not all such interactions are good, but there is some good to be found.)

With this stipulated, what then is the purpose of lobbying? At its best, it highlights to a government a chance to get some of that good stuff by changing a rule. "Hey, if our people didn't need visas to come visit you, they would spend their money in your country. Here's a pile of research about how much money that might be and why you don't need to worry about them secretly staying after their visit." "Hey, we have a lot of [thing] that your people would really love to buy, but the tariffs are stopping them and that's making your own people sad, you can fix that by lowering the tariffs. Here's a spreadsheet."

Is that what most lobbyists are doing? Would most countries (as opposed to bribable individual decision makers) do better if they did what the well funded lobbyists are suggesting? Well, probably not **most**. Nevertheless the benefits exist and are the reason the mechanism exists openly and reasonably transparently. The open-ness is also supposed to be a sort of braking mechanism on the nudge-nudge-wink-wink "if you change this law the company your child owns would stand to do very well by it" stuff that surely also does happen.